# Accessing PhoneTextBox in ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7.1

I want to access value from PhoneTextBox named "buttonSearch" placed inside ListBox. The only problem is that i can't invoke it from code behind. What i mean is that i can easly do it like this:

```
string writtenText = buttonSearch.Text;
```

when PhoneTextBox is not inside ListBox.

MainPage.xaml:

```
<controls:PanoramaItem Name="panoramaSearch">
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ApiSearch}" Name="listboxSearch">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="panelSearch">
                            <toolkit:PhoneTextBox x:Name="buttonSearch" Hint="search" ActionIcon="Images/Search.png" Height="70" Width="350" ActionIconTapped="SearchIconTapped" />
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <Image Height="100" Width="100" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                                <StackPanel Width="311">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle3Style}" />
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Category}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSmallStyle}" />
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </controls:PanoramaItem>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
 private void SearchIconTapped(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     //here is place i want to get PhoneTextBoxValue
 }
```

My problem is that all i can access is ListBox named listboxSearch. I can't directly get value from PhoneTextBox. Is there a way to get that value?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a dependency property in MainPage.xaml.cs, let's call it `PhoneText`.

In your data template add to PhoneTextBox:

```
Text="{Binding PhoneText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Page}, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Then back in code-behind:

```
private void SearchIconTapped(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    var phoneTxt = PhoneText; //not really necessary, just to show usage
}
```